# How to display data from array after removing delimiters in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, parsing, html-parsing

I created an HTML form where a user can upload a text file and after upload, the contents of the text file will be displayed in the same page. The content of the sample text file is formatted like this:

**"last_name** (white spaces) **first_name** (white spaces) **middle_initial"**, "gender", "age"**

for example **"ADKINS** (white spaces) **ADELE** (white spaces) **L", "F", "26"**

The last, first name and middle initial are separated by white spaces. The output that I would like to achieve is something like this:

> Last Name: ADKINS
>
> First Name: ADELE
>
> Middle initial: L
>
> Gender: F
>
> Age: 26

I have used the function `preg_split` to remove the quotation marks and commas. I have also stored the contents of the text file in an array. My problem is that whenever I display the values of each index in the array, I only get **ADKINS**. The first name and middle initial is not displayed because it is in a different array location. *[THIS PART IS SOLVED: Also, I cannot display the gender and the age.]*

Here's my code for displaying the information:

```
foreach($rows as $row => $data){
$row_data = preg_split('/[",]/',$data);

$info[$row]['lastname'] = $row_data[1];
$info[$row]['firstname'] = $row_data[2];
$info[$row]['middle'] = $row_data[3];
$info[$row]['gender'] = $row_data[4];
$info[$row]['age'] = $row_data[5];  

echo 'Last Name: ' . $info[$row]['lastname'] . '<br>'
echo 'First Name: ' . $info[$row]['firstname'] . '<br>'
echo 'Middle Initial: ' . $info[$row]['middlename'] . '<br>'
echo 'Gender: ' . $info[$row]['lastname'] . '<br>'
echo 'Age: ' . $info[$row]['lastname'] . '<br>'`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the easiest way would actually be this:

```
$row_data = explode(',', $data);
$row_data = str_replace('"', '', $row_data);
$names = explode(' ', $row_data[0]);

echo 'Last Name: ' . $names[1] . '<br>'
echo 'First Name: ' . $names[0] . '<br>'
echo 'Middle Initial: ' . $names[2] . '<br>'
echo 'Gender: ' . $row_data[1] . '<br>'
echo 'Age: ' . $row_data[2] . '<br>'`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($rows as $data) {
    $arr = json_decode("{".$data."}");

    if(count($arr) == 3) {
        $names = explode(' ', $arr[0]);

        if(count($names) == 3) {
            echo 'Last Name: ' . $names[1] . '<br>';
            echo 'First Name: ' . $names[0] . '<br>';
            echo 'Middle Initial: ' . $names[2] . '<br>';
            echo 'Gender: ' . $arr[1] . '<br>';
            echo 'Age: ' . $arr[2] . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Regular Expression, you can use code below

```
preg_match_all("/(\w|\d)+/", $data, $output);
print_r($output[0]);
```